# function get call multiple times

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, cordova

Hi all I have suppose two html files in my mobile application say page1.html and page2.html.  In page2.html I have one table and on click of row I had shown an alert. If Suppose I go from page1 to page2.html then on click of table it show alert box one time. If I press back button then It go to page1.html If suppose I go again on page2.html and I click on table row then this time alert display 2 times. IF I go back again on page1 and come again on page2.html then this time on click of row it show alert 3 times and so on...

My page2.html table look like:

```
<div id="myTable"  align="center"  data-theme="b"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 

var theader = '<table border="1" id=\"tableId\">\n';

                    var colheader = '<tr id="headingtab" bgcolor="#D68B8B"><th>Name</th><th>Address</th><th>City</th><th>LTP</th><th>State</th><th>Country</th><th>Mob No</th></tr>\n';
                    tbody = colheader; 


                    tbody += '<td>';
                        tbody += "QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ";
                        tbody += '</td>';

                        tbody += '<td>';
                       tbody += "QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ";
                        tbody += '</td>'

                        tbody += '<td>';
                        tbody += "QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ";
                        tbody += '</td>'

                        tbody += '<td>';
                       tbody += "QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ";
                        tbody += '</td>'

                        tbody += '<td>';
                        tbody += "QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ";
                        tbody += '</td>'

                        tbody += '<td>';
                        tbody += "QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ";
                        tbody += '</td>'

                        tbody += '<td>';
                        tbody += "QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ";
                        tbody += '</td>'                             


                        tbody += '</tr>\n';

                        var tfooter = '</table>';
                        document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML = theader + tbody + tfooter;

                        </script>


 <script type="text/javascript">


            $("#tableId tr td").live("click",function()
            {    
                console.log("??????????????????????????????");

                alert("Row Click");

            });


    </script>
    </div>
```

I want only one time alert shown on each click. How to do that? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I use `e.stopImmediatePropagation();`as :

```
$("#tableId").die('click', 'tr td').live('click', 'tr td', function (){
            alert ("Click");
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();

            });
```

Then it gives me proper result, but If I use `e.stopPropagation();  then it is not work.

By the way Thank you guys `fredrik,Ashirvad Singh,Arjun T Raj`  for your time and response.  Any other suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use jquery function  .one()

```
$(#tableId tr td).one("click",function()
            {    
                console.log("??????????????????????????????");

                alert("Row Click") 
}
```

[check this](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

This may help you

Comment: Thanks for response, But using $(#tableId tr td).one("click",function() alert not display.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
  $("#tableId tr td").click(function()
        {    
            console.log("??????????????????????????????");

            alert("Row Click");

        });
```

**EDIT**
[FIDDLE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/krmKL/)

Comment: Thanks for reply , but using $("#tableId tr td").click(function()
 it is not showing alert (not even single).

Comment: check out the fidlle. is not that you wanted?

Comment: Yes you are code works on fiddle but not on mobile simulator.If I use my original code [link](http://fiddle.jshell.net/krmKL/1/) then also it works in fiddle but not on mobile simulator.

Comment: i see an extra </div>
 close tag last line.. which does not have any opening <div> tag . Is that causing the problem?

Comment: actually it was main div, it was not extra, actually I had not given whole html page here(means starting of that div).

Answer (score 0):

The problem occur due to that event handler is bound each time page2.html is loaded. I would guess the page is loaded with Ajax? This means that each time the page is loaded the event handler is added, and since it's Ajax the JavaScript event handlers is still present. The event handlers are present until you remove them your self of you to a complete page reload.

The best solution is to only add the event handler once in you base page (the page that does all ajax loading).

An other solution is to first unbind your old event handlers and the add your new ones.

```
$("#tableId tr td").unbind('click').live('click'.....
```

Even better is to use jQuery's delegator method:

```
$("#tableId").die('click', 'tr td').live('click', 'tr td'.....
```

Comment: If I use $("#tableId").off('click', 'tr td').on('click', function(){    alert("Click")});  Then it is not showing any alert.

Comment: You need `.on('click', 'tr td', function () { alert('click'); });`

Comment: I had also tried with .on('click', 'tr td', function () { alert('click'); });  but it does not work, it is not showing alert. Only $("#tableId").live('click', 'tr td', function () works, but same issue as of multiple alert box.

Comment: Thanks for response, here using $("#tableId").die('click', 'tr td').live('click', 'tr td', function (){ alert ("Cliasck");}); it show now alert but still have multiple alert problem.